# Counting the size of the largest sets of independent strings

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics

This question derives from a [PPCG coding challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54354/find-the-largest-independent-set-in-a-high-dimensional-lattice-like-graph) I posed previously but despite asking on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393993/counting-the-size-of-the-largest-sets-of-independent-strings) and offering a bounty, no progress has been made.

For a given positive integer $n$, consider all binary strings of length $2n-1$.  For a given string $S$, let $L$ be an array of length $n$ which contains the count of the number of $1$s in each substring of length $n$ of $S$. For example, if $n=3$ and $S = 01010$ then $L=[1,2,1]$. We call $L$ the counting array of $S$.

We say that two strings $S1$ and $S2$ of the same length *match* if their respective counting arrays $L1$ and $L2$ have the property that $L1[i] \leq 2*L2[i]$ and $L2[i] \leq 2*L1[i]$ for all $i$.

**Problem**

For increasing $n$ starting at $n=1$, we want to compute the size of the largest set of strings, each of length $2n-1$ so that no two strings match.

**Known answers**

For $n=1,2,3,4,5$ the optimal answers are $2,4,10,16,31$.

For $n=6,7,8,9,10$, the best known values are $47, 76, 112, 168, 235$ from a combination of the answers of joriki and Peter Taylor.

**The question**

Plotting these values they appear to be subexponential but it is hard to say much more than that. This leads to the question:

> How do optimal solutions scale with $n$?

Comment: An experimental observation: let $G_n$ be the directed graph with strings as vertices, and an edge from $S_1$ to $S_2$ if $L_1\leqslant 2L_2$. Then the transitive reduction of $G_n$ contains a "dominating" cycle: of order $7$ for $n=2$, of order $29$ for $n=3$, of order $120$ for $n=4$, ...

Comment: Here's an idea for dealing with strings that are not outrageously sparse: take a string, split it up into blocks of length $n/10$, say. For each block, store $\lfloor 10\log_2$(weight)$\rfloor$. If two strings have the same weight vector (and are not ridiculously sparse), then they match. Since there are only $(\log n)^{20}$ weight vectors, this should give a good bound on non-sparse independent sets...